# SSL error with curl in Openshift

Tags: mongodb, ssl, curl, openshift, mlab

I ssh to my app in Openshift and make POST request (to mlab database mongoDB server) with curl like this:

```
curl --trace -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"m":"hihihi","t":"category","tid":"393"}'  https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/babi/collections/massrequest?apiKey=CvI9xC12d4dgjxTncXLz_y-PqNhqwP7RE
```

The trace result show that:

```
== Info: About to connect() to api.mlab.com port 443 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 54.144.240.132... == Info: connected
== Info: Connected to api.mlab.com (54.144.240.132) port 443 (#0)
== Info: Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
== Info:   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
== Info: NSS error -12286
== Info: Closing connection #0
== Info: SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

I dont know why I can not connect to mLab API with this POST request. Is there any one got this problem like me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the curl version. On my OpenShift account, I see it's very old:

```
[mydomain.com [...]]\> curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.18 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

See here for the same problem: [curl: (35) SSL connect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787413/curl-35-ssl-connect-error?rq=1)