# php curl ssl error no 35

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I couldn't esablish connection with bankim.az.
Here is my code:

```
$curl = $this->curl;
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS, false);
//$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
$curl->get('https://bankim.az/');
if ($curl->error) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $curl->errorCode . ': ' . $curl->errorMessage . "\n";
}
```

And I got this error:

```
Error: 35: SSL connect error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to bankim.az:443
```

I am using php7 ubuntu with root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use your custom code or you need to post full code here. This code will work:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://bankim.az/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS, false);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>İnternet Şöbə v3.1</title>
...
```

Comment: It returns bool(false)

Comment: So the problem is come from your machine, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787413/curl-35-ssl-connect-error

Comment: but my curl is latest version

Comment: Check another conditions like datetime