# How to FIX "ovirtsdk4.Error: Error while sending HTTP request:" error in oVirt

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to backup the VM on the server through the Python API interface, and I backup the VM via ovirt-engine. How do I backup using Ovirtsdk4?

I've tried a number of times, still errors

```
import logging
import ovirtsdk4 as sdk

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='example.log')

def get_connection():
    # Create the connection to the server:
    return sdk.Connection(
        url='https://172.32.42.75/ovirt-engine/api',
        username='admin@internal',
        password='password',
        ca_file='/etc/pki/ovirt-engine/ca.pem',
        debug=True,
        log=logging.getLogger(),
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Set VM name
    vm_name = 'myvm'

    # Create a connection to the server:
    connection = get_connection()

    # Get a reference to the root service:
    system_service = connection.system_service()

    # Get the reference to the "vms" service:
    vms_service = system_service.vms_service()

    # Locate VM service
    try:
        vm = vms_service.list(search="name=%s" % vm_name, all_content=True)[0]
        ovf_filename = "%s.ovf" % vm.id
        with open(ovf_filename, "wb") as ovf_file:
            ovf_file.write(vm.initialization.configuration.data)
    finally:
        # Close the connection to the server:
        connection.close()
```

I hope the VM that will do the backup can run properly using the Python API oVirt.[error of ovirtsdk4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaFQ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think error might be because of older curl. Please update curl, libcurl and NSS libraries and try again.

Ref: [curl: (35) SSL connect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787413/curl-35-ssl-connect-error)